# 552 user@domain is Black-Listed! in reply to Mail From command

Tags: email, postfix, domain, blacklist

For the last few days we are having some issues with few server we administrate. The remote servers are throwing the following error.

552 user@domain is Black-Listed! in reply to Mail From command

However none of the IP's are in the blacklists and this error occurs randomly. Google search did not bring any useful information. Can someone help me with this issue.

Comment: Do you manage the remote servers ? Could you have the logs ? Do you check the logs in your server

Comment: @Dom I do not manage the remote servers unfortunaately.  In my logs I can see status=bounced (host  said: 552 email@domain is Black-Listed! (in reply to MAIL FROM command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the reason for this error. AN ISP of our country (SLT) has put a spam filter in front of their ADSL internet connections. Some of our customers use ADSL connections with static IP addresses for email servers. The ISP's spam filter returns the error "552 user@domain is Black-Listed!" but it looks like the remote server is sending these errors.